# Difference between score and accuracy_score in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Whats the difference between `score()` method in `sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB()` module and `accuracy_score` method in `sklearn.metrics` module? Both appears to be same. Is that correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, different models have score methods that return different metrics. This is to allow classifiers to specify what scoring metric they think is most appropriate for them (thus, for example, a least-squares regression classifier would have a `score` method that returns something like the sum of squared errors). In the case of `GaussianNB` the docs say that its score method:

> Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

The `accuracy_score` method says its return value depends on the setting for the `normalize` parameter:

> If False, return the number of correctly classified samples. Otherwise, return the fraction of correctly classified samples.

So it would appear to me that if you set `normalize` to `True` you'd get the same value as the `GaussianNB.score` method.

One easy way to confirm my guess is to build a classifier and call both `score` with `normalize = True` and `accuracy_score` and see if they match. Do they?

Comment: Did you try it out @Oliver Dain? did it work in your case? This would help other understand the answer more completely and fully.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the proof.

```
# Test score vs accuracy_score

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB 
multinom = MultinomialNB()
multinom.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_pred_multinom = multinom.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred_multinom = multinom.predict(X_test)

score = multinom.score(X_test, y_test)
acc_score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_test_pred_multinom, normalize = True)

print(f'Score:', score)
print(f'Accuracy Score:', acc_score)
```

Result:

```
Score: 0.9686274509803922
Accuracy Score: 0.9686274509803922
```