# How to score and measure accuracy on a model in python (Titanic Dataset, RandomForestRegressor)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've created a model is trained on the titanic dataset, and I want to see an accuracy percentage for my model. I've done this before, but sadly, I do not remember. I looked at the internet, and I couldn't find anything. Either I just entered the wrong words, or there isn't anything their.

```
# the tts function is `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = tts(X, y, random_state = 0) # y is the state of survival

forest_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0)
forest_model.fit(train_X, train_y)
val_predictions = forest_model.predict(val_X)
```

How can I calculate the accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why are you using `RandomForestRegressor`, as titanic dataset can be formulated as a binary-classification problem. Assuming it is a mistake, to measure accuracy you can of a `RandomForestClassifier`, you can do:

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
>>> accuracy_score(val_y, val_predictions)
```

However, it is often better to use [`K-fold cross-validation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), which gives you more reliable accuracy:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> cross_val_score(forest_model, X, y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy') #10-fold cross validation, notice that I am giving X,y not X_train, y_train
```

[`K-fold cross-validation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) gives you 10 accuracy values of accuracy, as it divides the data into 10 folds (i.e. parts). Then, you can get a `mean` and `standard deviation` the accuracy values as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> accuracy =  np.array(cross_val_score(forest_model, X, y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy'))
>>> accuracy.mean() #mean of accuracies
0.81
>>> accuracy.std() #standard deviation of accuracies
0.04
```

You can also use other scoring metric such as `F1-score`, `Precision`,
`Recall`,`cohen_kappa_score` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the model score to know the performance accuracy

```
forest_model.score(val_y, val_predictions)
```

Comment: What is the difference between score() and accuracy_score()?

Comment: please go through trough this link here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726899/difference-between-score-and-accuracy-score-in-sklearn#:~:text=In%20the%20case%20of%20GaussianNB,number%20of%20correctly%20classified%20samples.)